# "The raised beds provide too much square footage to plant out entirely every season"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I came across this sentence on a forum regarding composting but I could understand what it means.

For me the sentence is like

The elevated beds provide too much place to plant out ..But what it means in the following context?

> It's difficult to keep the compost pile wet enough to produce good hot
>   compost - the heat and the sun in Florida dries it out too quickly.
>   **And the raised beds provide too much square footage to plant out entirely every season -** I'd have way more veggies than our household
>   can handle. So my question is, rather than putting the kitchen waste -
>   vegetable and fruit trimmings and coffee grounds with filter - on the
>   compost heap and hoping for the best, could I just bury the waste in
>   an unused bed that would remain fallow until the next season, and
>   rotating the beds used for composting in this way each season? Is
>   there any reason why I shouldn't do this?

[Source](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/684464)

Comment: Does it mean " we have too much fallow land soil"

Answer (score 3):

"Plant out entirely" here means to fill the entire area with plants. The area (square footage) of the raised beds is too large for the author's needs; filling it with plants each season would produce more vegetables than the family could consume.

Answer (score 2):

"Raised beds" are like terraces. Square footage just means area or space.  She says she has more space in her garden than she needs to grow her food every year.